# Removed click handler but function still gets executed?

Tags: javascript, web

I have been having some problems with my node.js application, and I had to test the click handler of a sign in button. Even though I changed it (so it will not work), and I click on it, that piece of code still gets executed. Why is that? I emptied my cache.

Originally it was "#sign-in" as that's the button ID.

```
$("#ign-in").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
      $.ajax({
      url: '/api/sign-in',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
      },
      //success properyt meg fail propertyt kulon meghatarozni
      success: function (response, request) {
        window.location = response.redirectTo
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.alert(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).error.message)
      }
  })
})
```

HTML:

```
body
.container
  form(class='form-signin' role='form')
    h2.form-signin-heading Please Sign In
    input#email.form-control(type='email' placeholder='E-mail address' required='' autofocus='')
    input#password.form-control(type='password' placeholder='Password' required='')
    div.checkbox
      label(style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:0px;") Remember Me
        input(type='checkbox' value='remember-me' style="margin-left:-110px;")
      label
    button#sign-in.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Sign In
    button#forgot-pw.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Forgot Password?
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What does your HTML look like.

Comment: Where is the code that removes the click handler?

Comment: Adding a new click handler for `#ign-in` doesn't remove the existing click handler for `#sign-in`.

Comment: This is the code that still gets executed, so you changed the ID to reference `#ign-in` instead of `#sign-in` so it shouldn't get to the button you are clicking. We need to also see that `#sign-in` button's code as what *Sam* said above.

Comment: I thought if I change the click handler's reference to an incorrect one, the code wouldn't be linked to the button click any more? I updated the question with the HTML

Comment: Where are you removing the click handler? I can't see that in your code.

Comment: I modified the ID for the click handler to "ign-in" instead of "sign-in" so it no longer applies.

Comment: I figured it out!